# google app engine user service to login and logout java

Tags: java, google-app-engine, gwt

I am using user service to let the user login and logout , i want to make something like google bar at the top of the page which contains logout + your email, when ever you access any page you can find that bar .
Certainly i use that user service and checks whether the user has a full access to enter the page if so then i use div id="my page" else create a login URL , even when the user has been authenticated correctly he enters the page and when ever he clicks on a link he goes to another page (in the page i also use user service and login and out url ) here comes the problem when the user clicks logout in that page and try and login again he goes to the second page where he has clicked the logout URL not the home page ,  i want the user when ever he clicks logout he and try to login again he goes to the home page

Answer (score 2):

From the last line of your question, it sounds like you just want the logout button to go to the home page. From the [Users Java API](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/users/overview.html) - why not just do `userService.createLogoutURL(homePageURL)` (substituting homePageURL accordingly)?

Comment: from your word i got that i can customize my logout url ..? is that true